# Make the 'Check out these companies' sidebar have less aggressive colors in dark mode

Tags: feature-request, advertising, dark-mode, sidebar

I use Stack Overflow in dark mode.

It helps me concentrate and I found it more pleasant than the bright mode.

In general the menus and sidebars are well integrated in terms of colors, however recently I started seeing the "Check out these companies" sidebar with bright red which is completely annoying and destroying the dark mode benefits.

I understand that Stack Overflow earns some money from these ads and want us to draw out attention towards this sidebars, but the colors chosen are in my opinion excessive.

Could they be changed to darker tones? They will still be more visible than the other sections of the website, but also more friendly towards users.

I already reported the image as distracting.

[image]