# Bright, red, aggressive color ads in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, user-experience, advertising, dark-mode

This is related to the question [Make the 'Check out these companies' sidebar have less aggressive colors in dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420389/make-the-check-out-these-companies-sidebar-have-less-aggressive-colors-in-dark)

Stack Overflow seems to have been recently inundated by advertisements with bright red colors that are very distracting when browsing in dark mode.

An example of such picture in the dark background.

[image]

Other sections of Stack Overflow have less aggressive colors that blend well with both the dark and white backgrounds:

[image]

I find seeing such bright, red, aggressive ads very annoying and distracting.

I think Stack Overflow should review ads before they are published and not allow such advertisements, at least not with these color tones.

I understand advertisers want their ads to be noticed, but there should be a range of saturation/brightness allowed that doesn't impact so aggressively on the user.

A darker red will still catch attention while being more user-friendly.

Comment: https://ublockorigin.com/

Comment: Another option is to gain enough reputation to disable certain ads: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads

Comment: I have more than 200 privilege points. This ads are not the banner ones that you get when you are a new user.

Comment: If I were to write this post, I would `s/aggressive/offensive/`.

Comment: As someone who's red/green colorblind I know instinctively those aren't the same color but holy cow

Comment: Voting to reopen, how is this post not about Stack Overflow? If you disagree with the post downvote it, disagreement is not a closure reason.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Because it's about an ad, not about Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TylerH You managed to write an answer relating it to Stack Overflow.  I also believe that Stack Overflow sells their own ad space, so they _could_ issue policies, regardless of whether they are likely to issue any _particular_ policy.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to use the Internet without an ad blocker while maintaining your sanity these days. Is there a reason why you aren't using one? Also, once you have high enough rep you can opt out of seeing ads.

Comment: "I'd like to surf the internet without seeing the color #ca2737". I think ad creators can use whatever colors they want, and IMHO this one isn't even that bad. It could've been #f00.

Comment: It's bad enough for me to install an ad blocker. If this is what StackOverflow forces us to do, this is what we will do.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Installing an ad blocker is good, not bad.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Because you like to view ads and to have big multinational companies spy on your internet activity, or...? Install at least one ad blocker and also anti-trackers. Block tracking cookies. From there on, you'll almost be able to use the Internet like back in the days, before it turned into Google's personal playground.

Comment: I guess I know now why the colours have been made so washed out: so that advertisements would stand out more…

Answer (score 19):

The point of using the color red is to grab attention, so this appears to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) as far as the advertiser is concerned. I doubt Stack Overflow would issue rules such as "you can't use a primary color in your ads". It's also more noticeable here on this Meta question because Meta has a white background and you've cropped the image to just show the ad and the slightest amount of black around it, not to mention it is clearly zoomed in/increased in size from the actual size.

Your best bet is to just deal with seeing the color red when browsing the internet, or use an ad blocker if you don't want to see ads. You can also use a userscript or user style for relevant sites to change the color red to some other color that doesn't bother you.

Comment: Also the ad was probably not designed with any particular site in mind.

Comment: An option for a dark mode version of an ad might be cool.

Comment: I strongly believe that SO issuing some rules regarding dominant ad colors is the proper thing to do.